# Issue with displaying response message from server in a pop up modal in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I created a two custom dialog modals inside an angular component. My goal is to open the correct modal and show the response message.

The component receiving two values as `Observable` from my services:

1. The modal-name that needs to be open
2. The response message that was returned from the server

From some reason the component displaying the message ONLY in the first time that one of the modals getting opened, **although it shown in the console that the value assigned properly** (the modals are working fine).

Any help solving this issue will be appreciated

*Component Ts*

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
    import { ShowHallService } from '../../admin-panel/admin-services/show-Hall.service';
    import { AlertModalService } from '../alert-modal.service';
    import { AdminMovieService } from '../../admin-panel/admin-services/admin-movie.service';
    import { ShowService } from '../../admin-panel/admin-services/shows.service';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-alert-modal',
      templateUrl: './alert-modal.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./alert-modal.component.scss']
    })
    export class AlertModalComponent implements OnInit {


     private showHallModalSub: Subscription;
     private responseMessage: string;


      constructor(private modalService: AlertModalService,
                  private showHallService: ShowHallService,
                  private movieService: AdminMovieService,
                  private showService: ShowService,
                  private router: Router) { }


      ngOnInit() {
         this.showHallModalSub = this.showHallService.getAlertModalInfo().subscribe((response) => {  
          this.responseMessage = response.message  
          this.openModal(response.modalName)   
        })

        this.showHallModalSub = this.movieService.getAlertModalInfo().subscribe((response) => {
         this.responseMessage = response.message 
         this.openModal(response.modalName)     
        })
      }


      // Modal function - getting the info about which modal needs to be open 
      openModal(modalName:string){
        this.modalService.open(modalName);
        setTimeout(() => {
          if(modalName === 'success-modal'){
            this.modalService.close(modalName);
             this.router.navigate(["/admin"])
          }
          this.modalService.close(modalName);
        }, 2000);
      }


      ngOnDestroy(): void {
          this.showHallModalSub.unsubscribe();
      }
    }
```

*Conmpoennt Html*

```
<!-- Success Modal -->
  <alert-modal id="success-modal">
    <div class="success-modal">
      <div class="success-modal__circle">
        <div class="success-modal__icon"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div class="success-modal__body">
        <h3 class="success-modal__main-text">Success!</h3>
        <p class="success-modal__sub-text">{{responseMessage}}</p>
      </div>
      <!-- Optional -->
      <div class="success-modal__btn">
      </div>
    </div>
  </alert-modal>
  <!--  End success Modal -->




  <!-- fail Modal -->
  <alert-modal id="fail-modal">
    <div class="fail-modal">
      <div class="fail-modal__circle">
        <div class="fail-modal__icon"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div class="fail-modal__body">
        <h3 class="fail-modal__main-text">Failed!</h3>
        <p class="fail-modal__sub-text">{{responseMessage}}</p>
      </div>
      <!-- Optional -->
      <div class="fail-modal__btn">
      </div>
    </div>
  </alert-modal>
  <!--End fail Modal -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok.
The problem was that i had the template of the modal inside the HTML of another component that was opened in the same time in the Dom.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

Insall jQuery

> Add inside Component:

```
 declare var $: any;
```

> After it, you can open modal with jquery code easily with add this service Observable.

```
$("#myModal").modal('show');
```